# What is Redirect URI in Youtube API?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, google-oauth

I'm creating a personal python script to upload videos. What is the redirect API I should be using?

Comment: Learn how OAuth works.

Comment: I have a basic understanding of how oauth works, but I'm just confused on using it on cases where I don't have an application website or installed app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect URI For a Web Application-

Applications that use languages and frameworks like PHP, Java, Python, Ruby, and .NET must specify authorized redirect URIs. The redirect URIs are the endpoints to which the OAuth 2.0 server can send responses.

Check this page for further explanation 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps

Comment: But if I'm using a python script that's just going to run in my system, what would the redirect uri be? Is it my IP?